# Mysql sum from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got an database where every user has an uid, but can login with an different nickname each time (table A). Now the user can buy stuff and and I am saving the login id and the price (table B). I made an example, note that Nick and NickRenamed are the same person as they have the same uid

Table A

```
id  |  nickname   |  uid
1   | Nick        |  abcdef
2   | Nack        |  ab1234
3   | NickRenamed |  abcdef
```

Table B

```
id  |  idA  | price
1   |   1   |   200
2   |   1   |   400
3   |   2   |    20
4   |   3   |    75
```

For an statistic I want to get every (distinct) uid, the latest nickname and sum the price of this user

```
uid    | nickname    |  price_total
abcdef | NickRenamed |   675
ac1234 | Nack        |    20
```

My approch was

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A.uid)
     , A.id
     , A.nickname
     , SUM(B.price) 
  FROM A 
  JOIN B 
    ON A.id = B.idA 
 GROUP 
    BY A.uid
```

but an error gets thrown

```
Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated 
column 'test.A.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in 
GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: All your non-aggregated columns must be in `GROUP BY` statement.  In your case `GROUP BY A.uid, A.id, A.nickname`.

Comment: Also, note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in your query is that you can only use columns on which grouping is done and aggregate functions with select clause.

So the correct query will be-

```
SELECT A.uid,SUM(B.price) FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.idA GROUP BY A.uid;
```

You cannot print name with these because you are creating virtual groups on uid and there are two names with uid = 'abcdef'.

Answer (score 0):

You need two separated queries for that.

First to find out the sum of each user

```
SELECT uid, SUM(price) as total
FROM TableA TA
JOIN TableB TB
  on Ta.id = Tb.idA
GROUP BY uid
```

Now to get the latest name of each user.

```
SELECT nickname, uid
FROM TableA T1
LEFT JOIN TableA T2
  ON T1.id > T2.id
 AND T1.uid = T2.uid
WHERE T2.id IS NULL
```

Now put both together

```
 SELECT step1.uid, 
        step2.nickname,
        step1.total

 FROM (    SELECT uid, SUM(price) as total
           FROM TableA TA
           JOIN TableB TB
             on Ta.id = Tb.idA
           GROUP BY uid) as step 1
 JOIN (    SELECT nickname, uid
           FROM TableA T1
           LEFT JOIN TableA T2
             ON T1.id > T2.id
            AND T1.uid = T2.uid
           WHERE T2.id IS NULL ) as step2
  on step1.uid = step2.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this approach:

```
  select
    uid,nickname,sum(price) total
  from
  (
      select
      A.uid,
      A.nickname,
      (B.price) price
      from
      tableA A
      inner join TableB B
      on A.id = B.ida
      order by A.uid,A.id desc)cs
  group by cs.uid
```

#### SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1d345/35

Answer (score -1):

```
select TableA.uid, TableA.nickname, sum(tableB.Price), max(TableA.id)
from tableA, TableB
where Tablea.uid=tableB.uid
group by TableA.udi
```

Comment: First of all, please use a proper join.  Secondly, it won't work.  Same problem as OP's problem, TableA.nickname is not in GROUP BY.